# ChefSpec unable to find cookbook

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chefspec

When I run my unit test case (written in ChefSpec) I get the following error:

> Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook azuredns not found. If
>   you're loading azuredns from another cook book, make sure you
>   configure the dependency in your metadata

Following are my spec file, recipe file and metadata file

azuredns/spec/get_azure_token_spec.rb

```
require 'chefspec'
require 'rest-client'

describe 'azuredns::get_azure_token' do
  let(:chef_run) do
    # Step into the provider
    runner = ChefSpec::SoloRunner.new(step_into: ['azuredns_token'])
    # Read test data from a json file
    file_path = File.expand_path('test_data.json', __dir__)
    file = File.open(file_path)
    contents = file.read
    node_attr = JSON.parse(contents)
    # Load test data into node object
    runner.node.consume_attributes(node_attr)
    runner.converge(described_recipe)
  end

  before(:each) do
    # Mock post method of RestClient
    allow(RestClient).to receive(:post)
      .and_return({ access_token: 'i-am-a-token' }.to_json)
  end

  it 'retrieves token' do
    expect(chef_run).to retrieve_azuredns_token('azure_token')
  end

  it 'varifies the expected value of azure_rest_token' do
    expect(chef_run.node['azure_rest_token']).to eq('Bearer i-am-a-token')
  end

  it 'does not retrieve token due to incorrect resource name' do
    expect(chef_run).to_not retrieve_azuredns_token('azure_token1')
  end

  it 'raises exception due to error in response' do
    # Mock post method of RestClient
    allow(RestClient).to receive(:post)
      .and_return({ error: 'invalid_grant' }.to_json)
    expect { chef_run }.to raise_error(Exception)
  end
end
```

azuredns/recipe/get_azure_token.rb

```
require 'rest_client'
require 'json'

cloud_name = node['workorder']['cloud']['ciName']
cloud = node['workorder']['services']['dns'][cloud_name]
dns_attributes = cloud['ciAttributes']

#  Establish connection and get a security token
token = azuredns_token 'azure_token' do
  tenant_id dns_attributes['tenant_id']
  client_id dns_attributes['client_id']
  client_secret dns_attributes['client_secret']
end

token.run_action(:retrieve)
```

azuredns/metadata.rb

```
name             'Azuredns'
maintainer       'Shaffan'
maintainer_email 'shaffan.chaudhry1@gmail.com'
license          'Apache License, Version 2.0'
description      'Installs/Configures Azure DNS'
version          '0.1.0'
depends          'azure'
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

`Azuredns` != `azuredns` :-)

Fix the name in your metadata. Chef, and pretty much everything from the UNIX world, is case sensitive.

Comment: This is our coding convention to keep the first letter capital.

Comment: when I change my test case like this: describe "Azuredns::get_azure_token"
I get this error: "No resource or method azuredns_token in get_azure_token.rb recipe"
That is, it is unable to find my custom resource(LWRP)

Comment: Yes, because again, you would have to use `Azuredns_token`. It's *all* case sensitive which is why you should fix the name instead.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure why we even allow uppercase in cookbook names, we should probably stop doing that.

Comment: Again, your standard is wrong and you are fixing the wrong problem. You'll have more issues like this in the future.

Comment: You are right. I had to capitalize the cookbook name in depends attr of metadata.rb file: 'depends "Azure"' instead of 'depends "azure"'. Also capitalize the Azure cookbook name in its metadata.rb file. Which is causing error in integration testing: Cookbook 'Azure' not found.

Comment: Is it really so hard to understand? Do not apply your naming convention for chef cookbooks. Period.